# Multiple questions with radiobutton answers not posting back answer value

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, radio-button

I have a form with multiple questions on it, each with their respective answers using radio buttons for the answers.  In my controller, when I get the form collection, the keys hold the question id and not the selected answer id, I need the answer id to update the db correctly.

Here are my models:

```
public class AccreditationEditModel
{
    public int AccreditationID { get; set; }
    public int UserID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
    public List<QuestionEditModel> Questions { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "User")]
    public string UserFullName { get; set; }
```

}

```
public class AnswerEditModel
{
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string AnswerText { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionEditModel
{
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
    public List<AnswerEditModel> Answers { get; set; }
    public int AnswerID { get; set; }
}
```

The view:

```
<table>
@foreach (var Question in Model.Questions)
{ 
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
            <div>
                <strong>@Question.QuestionText</strong>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    foreach (var Answer in Question.Answers)
    { 
        <tr>
           <td colspan="2">
                <input style="width:10px" type="radio" id="answer_id_@Answer.AnswerID" name="Question_@Answer.QuestionID" value="@Answer.AnswerID">@Answer.AnswerText
           </td>
        </tr>
    }
}
</table>
<p>
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</p>
```

and my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection model)
{
    try
    {
        id = UserPersistance.UserId(Request);
        Accreditation a = new Accreditation();
        a.LoadByUserID(id);
        a.DateCompleted = DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime();
        a.Save();       //Get an ID for the accreditation table for new.




        return RedirectToAction("Details");
    }
    catch
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Comment: why aren't you using razor to create the radio button?

Comment: I had trouble grouping the radio buttons by question, so that only one answer is possible per question.

Comment: you could use Razor, and set the `name=Answer.QuestionID` for grouping

Comment: This syntax does not do it: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => Answer.AnswerID, @Answer.QuestionID, new { name=@Answer.QuestionID })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't use `foreach`.  Use a `for loop` so you can relate it directly to your model:

```
for(int i=0; i< model.Questions.Count;i++)
{ 
    model.Question[i].QuestionText

    for(int j=0; j<model.Question[i].Answers.Count; j++)
    { 
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Question[i].Answers[j], model.Questions[i].QuestionID, new { @name = model.Questions[i].QuestionID})
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [article](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/Understanding-ASP-NET-MVC-Model-Binding.aspx) which explains binding to complex type, i.e. class

All you need to do is provide correct name to the field that is bound to AnswerEditModel.AnswerID, e.g.: `name="Answers.AnswerdID"`